# Python save output as text file

Tags: python, string, api, text, google-calendar-api

I'm using Python for a school project and I wanted to use the Google Calendar API for it. I just followed Google's guide for it and I added the last bit to try and save the outputs onto a text file, however, the problem I'm having is that it's only saving the very last event. I'm not very experienced in Python, so any explanation why and how I can make it do what I want would be super duper helpful!

Thank you!

```
"""
    Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API. Creates a Google Calendar API
    service object and outputs a list of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """

from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import datetime

# Setup the Calendar API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                      maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))

print(start, event['summary'])

outFile = open('sample.txt' , 'w')
outFile.write((start))
outFile.write( str(event['summary']))
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like this:

```
outFile = open('sample.txt' , 'w')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])    
    outFile.write((start))
    outFile.write(str(event['summary']))
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This worked

Now how can I change the format of the date and time that is displayed?

I tried making

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d)

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong.

You are only saving only one value and writing it.

It should be like below:

```
outFile = open('sample.txt' , 'w')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))

    print(start, event['summary'])


    outFile.write((start))
    outFile.write( str(event['summary']))
    outFile.write('\n')
outFile.close()
```